# Android screen configuration qualifier - How to set both minimum width and minimum height?

Tags: android, screen-orientation

Table 2 of [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) page describes the configuration qualifier names which can be used as directory names to specify minimum screen width or minimum screen height necessary for the values in the directory to take effect.

For an example, `w720dp` requires the device to have at least 720dp width in current orientation for the values to take effect, while `h720dp` requires at least 720dp height to be available.

Is there any way I can specify both the minimum height and the minimum width in the configuration qualifier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can specify both the minimum height and the minimum width in the configuration qualifier?

Use `-w720dp-h720dp`.